# Hover different object with css

Tags: css, hover

How to display an iframe code by mouse over (hover) a different link? I tried this but it's not working;

```
<style>
iframe#xyz {
    border: 2px solid #9a9a9a;
    margin-left: 60px;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 25px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
}

a#abc:hover iframe#xyz {
    border: 2px solid #9a9a9a;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: -18px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 25px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
}
</style>

<a class="linkclass" id="abc" href="link">link</a>
<iframe id="xyz" src="page.html"></iframe>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: can u add your work file in snippet

Comment: The iframe needs to be within the a's opening and closing tags

Comment: @JosephYoung it works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're selecting it wrong, use:

```
a#abc:hover {
    border: 2px solid #9a9a9a;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: -18px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 25px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Select a link with an id of `abc`.

If you want to show the iframe however, you must use the sibling selector `+`

use this:

```
a#abc:hover + #xyz {
    border: 2px solid #9a9a9a;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: -18px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 25px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
    #xyz{
        display: none;
    }
    .linkclass:hover + #xyz{
        display: block;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" class="linkclass">Click Here To View Map</a>
     <iframe id="xyz" src="#" width="870" height="300"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```